# "Now I am become death, the destroyer of worlds"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Is become” vs “has become”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-become-vs-has-become)

This is a famous quote from [J. Robert Oppenheimer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Robert_Oppenheimer) after the successful detonation of the first nuclear weapon. The quote comes from the Bhagavad Gita, a sacred Hindu scripture.

This quote has bothered me since I first read it. Is it grammatically correct to say *Now I am become death*? Shouldn't the quote say *Now I have become death* or just *Now I am death*?