# Is the meme, "all your base are belong to us" correct for any time period?

Tags: grammaticality

Surely many people have heard, “[all your base are belong to us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)”. It is a popular internet meme from 2000.

The *Wikipedia* page calls it “broken English”, but it seems as if some translations of *The Bible* use the same construction, as evident in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/71009/14451):

> Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new. —*II Corinthians 5:17*

If “all things are become new” is correct, then could “all your base are belong to us” also be correct? Do both of these follow the same form?

Comment: The 'God' questions are not easily answerable here. You should ask that at christianity.SE.

Comment: I edited out the first usage. I was uncomfortable editing out the final one though, as he made it part of his fundamental question.

Comment: I never understood what that means. Reading the Wiki, I still don't.

Comment: Related: [Is it acceptable to use "is become" instead of "has become"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become)

Answer (score 23):

No, they are completely different constructions.

*Become* in the phrase “are become” is the *past participle*, and the construction is an older form of “have become”. (It’s just a coincidence that *become* has the same form in its infinitive and its past participle).

Older English often used forms of *be* to form the perfect of some verbs, particularly verbs of motion, and verbs of change of state, where today we would use forms of *have*. You can find many examples of “is come”, “are arrived”, “is changed” and so on. The parallel construction is still used in French: “je suis arrivé” (“I am arrived”) as opposed to “j’ai vu” (“I have seen”).

But *belong* does not function as the past participle of *belong*: a parallel construction would be “they are belonged to”, which is not grammatical because *belong* is transitive (takes an object) so its perfect was never formed with *be*. In any case, the meaning of “all your base are belong to us” is not perfect.

Answer (score 5):

I’ll address the last question, “And, is it possible that they were both written under the direction of God almighty?”

*The Bible was not written in English.* Paul’s letters, in particular, were written in Greek. Some people *translated* it into English, but there are loads of such people, and if you check I think you’ll find most of those translations don’t use that construction, but a more modern one.

Comment: It is considered that the translations had God's influence.

Comment: @Mith - Addressing that really does belong over on christianity.se (Hint: it won't go over great even there). But simple logic says that English and Greek are different languages that do not perfectly map to each other, so translating the original `Corinthians` perfectly into English simply cannot be done, no matter how well guided.