# Function of the extra "to be" verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, syntactic-analysis

I was wondering a lot about it lately. I found various examples of it, specially in more formal/old texts.

The first time I realized it was reading what Oppenheiner said in an intreiew after the test with a nuclear bomb, he quotes the Bhagavad-gita and says:

> "Now I *am* become death, the destroyer of worlds.

What is this *am* doing there? What is its function? I am not an english native speaker, so I found it very tricky to find out the logic behind it, maybe some older tense I'm not aware of, or maybe "become" is not funcioning like a verb in an older context (but I think it is not as likely, knowing abou germanic languages in general).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Robert Oppenheimer's phrase “Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds.” grammatical in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433468/is-robert-oppenheimers-phrase-now-i-am-become-death-the-destroyer-of-worlds)

Comment: Yes! Thank you!