# "She is gone" versus "she has gone"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs

When should I say "She is gone", and when should I say "She has gone" (and why)?

I think that when I mean "She went away and she's still there", it should be "She has gone". Are there exceptions where it should be "She is gone" ?

Comment: Just say "she's gone"! :-)

Comment: @Tomas yes, that's what I'm doing now. I was just interested how is it in long form

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should normally use *be gone* if no direction is specified, *have gone* with directions:

> Where is Cleopatra? She is gone. *(= she is away, or dead)*
>
> Where is Cleopatra? She has gone to the temple.

This is idiom: it is irregular and only applies to very few verbs. And *is gone* can still be used with specific directions sometimes, though it is probably rare. The opposite *has gone* without direction doesn't sound wrong, but it is probably less frequent.

I believe *to be* + past participle was used to form the present perfect for all **intransitive** verbs in older English, just as in other Germanic languages: not *I have been* but *I am been*, etc. So it was once *he is gone* always, even with specific directions, as in modern Dutch *hij is naar huis gegaan*. Then at a certain point in time the default auxiliary verb for the present perfect of intransitive verbs changed to *have* in English; but some old, very frequent expressions stayed in use, like *to be gone* and some others.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Where is Cleopatra? She is dead/away." ?

Comment: @genesis: You could say "she is gone", and it would mean "she has left", or "she is dead"—something like that.

Comment: The context is important, so I don't think there's a simple answer right now.

Comment: @warm: Agreed. If the OP will give us more context, he will get a more specific answer.

Comment: One small quibble with the answer. There is nothing ungrammatical about using "has gone" even if no direction is specified (although in modern English it is incorrect to say "She is gone to ...").

Comment: @PeterShor: Sure, but then there is a slight difference in meaning, wouldn't you say? It's hard to pin down, but *she is gone* seems to emphasise movement, as opposed to *she has gone*, which emphasises that she is no longer here. I'd say *she is gone* would be more frequent;  the form *she's gone* is probably most frequent, and it could stand for both *is* and *has*, though I'd say it normally stands for *is*.

Comment: @PeterShor: I have added your suggestion that *has gone* without direction isn't wrong.

Comment: I'd say that 'She is gone' is quite rare to rare (especially as a complete statement) in Britain at least. And I'm guessing that 'She's gone' is normally considered a contraction of the has-form.

Comment: In "She is gone", gone shows a state.  'Go' being intransitive is not passivized here; but in "She has gone" gone is a verb in the active voice.

Answer (score 4):

The word *gone* here is a predicate adjective, meaning "no longer here". Etymologically, it came from the past participle of *go*, but in modern English it is also an adjective. Like the adjective *ready,* the adjective *gone* cannot usually be placed before a noun. Compare:

> The car was packed and ready.
> *The ready car was parked at the curb, waiting for them.
>
> When they looked in the cave, the treasure was gone.
> *They looked everywhere for the gone treasure.

The [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gone) does have examples where *gone* is used before a noun, but in most situations, placing *gone* before the noun is ungrammatical.

Comment: I suppose you could say that; after all, any participle is adjectival. Either description would work. However, I still prefer to analyse it as a participle, because your label would make it more difficult to describe the historical process that caused "she is gone" and "she has gone" to diverge. That is, historically, *gone* was a participle, and its usage never changed (it is only the auxiliary verb that changed).

Answer (score 1):

She HAS gone to the market

She is gone. (to mean, she left, she's away).

You can also use idioms like "what is gone and what is not...".... that is often used in literature.

Answer (score 1):

Another case in which the verb to be may be used to express the present or perfect tense is demonstrated in this question (now closed)
[Emily Dickinson poem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/557513/emily-dickinson-poem)

> A verse is bothering me:"Where is Jesus gone?" (From “Dying! Dying in the night!) [Emily Dickinson poem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/557513/emily-dickinson-poem)

Christians are brought up reading the Bible: often the King James Version.  The King James Version was published in 1611 and was written in a form of English that was even then old-fashioned.
As a result, they tend to use archaic language when formally expressing religious thoughts. Emily Dickinson (1830 –1886) was no exception.

The language of KJV1611 shows evidence, and many examples,  of the former use of the verb "to be" to form the present perfect and past perfect of intransitive verbs of motion and change.

Because of the Bible’s influence on the language, some of these forms are still used, particularly in dialect and colloquially.

> Mic:1:9: For her wound is incurable; for it **is come** unto Judah; he **is come** unto the gate of my people, even to Jerusalem.
>
> Ac:21:11: And when he **was come** unto us, he took Paul's girdle, and bound his own hands and feet,
>
> De:17:14: When thou **art come** unto the land which the LORD thy God giveth thee,
>
> 1Pe:3:22: **Who is gone** into heaven, and is on the right hand of God; angels and authorities and powers being made subject unto him.
>
> M't:26:71: And when he **was gone out** into the porch, another maid saw him,
>
> Ge:19:23: The sun **was risen** upon the earth when Lot entered into Zoar.
>
> Psalms:22:14: I am poured out like water, and all my bones are out of joint: my heart is like wax; it **is melted** in the midst of my bowels.
>
> Ac:7:40: Saying unto Aaron, Make us gods to go before us: for as for this Moses, which brought us out of the land of Egypt, we wot not what **is become** of him.
>
> 2Ki:4:18: And when the child **was grown**, it fell on a day, that he went out to his father to the reapers.
>
> Nu:35:32: And ye shall take no satisfaction for him that **is fled** to the city of his refuge, that he should come again to dwell in the land, until the death of the priest.

For a more modern use:

2009 [My Life Journal (from My Heart to Yours)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CSTrAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA127&dq=%22is%20gone%20to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpvfiVvJzuAhUKYcAKHfUDDuUQ6AEwCHoECCYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22is%20gone%20to%22&f=false) By V. K. Sansone *When he is gone to work, I feel lost, like there is a part of me that is missing and since I am "the rib", I guess it is the rest of my body that is gone.*

And the Google Ngram for "[is gone to,is become](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20gone%20to%2Cis%20become&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20gone%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20become%3B%2Cc0)"

Answer (score -3):

Using *is gone* is a sentence makes it passive tense, as in ''he is gone by someone's pressure'', while using *has gone* is active tense. I suppose this is the difference.