# "is gone" vs "has gone" and death

Tags: meaning, grammar

Can either "is gone" or "has gone" be used to refer to someone who has died? I know "is gone" is common, but I wonder if "has gone" carries the same meaning.

Comment: The be-perfect interpretation is discussed at [Is it acceptable to use 'is become' instead of 'has become'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become/3412#3412), but this is perhaps better analysed as the participial adjective usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["She is gone" versus "she has gone"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41453/she-is-gone-versus-she-has-gone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OED highlights a quotation under *go, (v.) 23. intr. a. In various phrases referring to a person's death, with the implicit notion of departing this world for an afterlife.*:

> His eyes stare. He has gone to the great recording studio in the sky.
>
> -- 1992 S. Tharoor *Show Business* (1995) ii. 94

So "has gone" does indeed carry the same meaning.

Comment: The death part seems more given by the _great recording studio in the sky_ than by the **has gone** itself. Do you have more examples?

Comment: @Helmar It's the only example I could find. You mean as in the simple "She is gone/she has gone"? I think they both make grammatical sense and the death bit is implied by context. And anyway, the whole "gone" thing is meant to imply that they have "gone" to an afterlife of some sort, of which "the great recording studio in the sky" is a metaphor.

Comment: *has gone to join the celestial choir* or *has gone to push up the daisies* or *has gone to kick the bucket* or ...

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes.

The word "gone" is the past participle of the *verb* "go." It is also used as an *adjective*.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gone

You only use *has/have* or *had* when using he Present Perfect Tense [has, have] or Past Perfect Tense [had].

He has gone. = the verb phrase "has gone" is in the Present Perfect to express an action (his dying) at no definite time in the past. When you say, "He has gone." you are referring to the fact he died some time ago (in the past).

He is gone. = without going too much into linking verbs, "is" is a linking verb linking the adjective "gone" (using one of the definitions for *gone* as an adjective) to describe the subject as "no longer living."

Comment: This is only partly true. _Go_ (as well as _(be)come_ and a few other verbs) used to quite regularly use _be_ as their auxiliary, and there are remnants of this still. _He is gone_ is one such remnant. It's not as cut-and-dried as, for example, the difference between “He is dead” and “He has died”. Sometimes you'll even still hear people affecting Ye Olde-Fashionèd Stile saying things like, “He is gone to the shops”.