# Emily Dickinson poem

Tags: grammar

i'm not an native english speaker.
I came across the "Dying ! Dying in the night " poem by E. Dickinson.

A verse is bothering me:

"Where is Jesus gone ?"

Is it grammaticaly correct ?
Would "Where has Jesus gone ?" be better ?

Or by her initial sentence, it means: where is he now that he is dead ?

I'm not implying that such an acclaimed poet could do grammar errors but i've never seen anything like this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ***Be gone***: 1) to be no longer in a particular place. 2)  to be dead or to no longer exist https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-gone

Comment: This is a good question, and the answer is very complicated, but we don't really do poetry analysis, much less hermeneutics, here. For a good answer, you might try [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). The short answer is that the line is grammatical. The now-gone Jesus must be somewhere if you accept the everlasting life claim; essentially, ever-lasting life is a special kind of life.

Comment: It is not at all obvious to me that the linked question provides an answer to the present question. The presence of *where* in the present question would seem to me to potentially make the analysis significantly different.

Comment: User JEL may be right that this is poetry analysis, and that the question is off-topic for that reason. But the linked question does not provide an answer.