# Is button been animated?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is it a proper English sentence: `Is button been animated?`?

It is possible at all to use the word `been` without `have` or `has`?

Comment: There are several issues, but that is not a standard English sentence

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sentence is not proper English because it uses present perfect progressive tense incorrectly.

Here is a description of the present perfect progressive tense (emphasis is mine):

> The present perfect progressive is formed from the **present tense of have**, **been (the past participle of be)** and **the past participle of the verb**. It is used to refer to something that has been going on in the past and is still going on.

[https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/writing/grammar/parts_of_speech/verbs.htm#mozTocId158155](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/writing/grammar/parts_of_speech/verbs.htm#mozTocId158155/)

This sentence meets the last two requirements for this tense, but not the first.

The only uses of **been** without **have** or **has** that I can think of are colloquial, where the **have** or **has** are implied. For example:

> "Been to downtown Las Vegas lately?" *(the **"have you"** is implied)*
>
> "Been a long time since we got together!" *(the **"it's"** or **"it has"** is implied)*

Comment: [I am become death, the destroyer of clumsy answers.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3415/300)

Comment: By this reasoning "has been" is never correct, either. "The word *has* is present tense, while *been* is only a past participle verb. Thus *has been, have gone, will do, was doing, will have been done* are all not proper English because the verb tenses do not match." Your words, not mine.

Comment: Agreed. The entire sentence is attempting to be in the present perfect progressive tense, but since that tense requires the word **has**, the sentence is incorrect.