# "the age is come"

Tags: tenses

When writing my book about a local history, I used as a heading:-
The Age of the Engineer is come", simply because I'm sure I've seen this usage elsewhere.
Am I OK with this, or have I got it round my neck?

Comment: The wording is a bit archaic.  "has come" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Doesn't sound that "archaic" to me in, say, [*The chickens are come home to roost.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22chickens+are+come+home%22) But yeah - ***have come*** is much more likely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You don't think "The chickens are come home to roost" is archaic???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it acceptable to use "is become" instead of "has become"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become)  You can easily find "is come" in Shakespeare!

Comment: come/came/come - says that the 3rd form of come is come, similar to become/ became/ become.  Assuming that we use the verbs come and become transitively, these change into 'is come' or 'is become'.  Can this be a way to look at it?

Comment: Why not simply: The Age of the Engineer?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the effect you're trying to create. Is there a reason why you want a portentious (or pretentious) tone?

If not, use *has*. In fact, if it's a title, use *Has* — and capitalize *Come*, too.