# when say: she's gone, which one is correct: she is gone or she has gone

Tags: phrase-requests

in this text:
"I can't find my daughter. I was buying these clothes at the register, 
  And she was right behing me, and now she’s gone."

written "she's gone". 
how I understand which one is mean?
she is gone?
or
she has gone?
thank you

Comment: It's 'has gone'. 'Is gone' was once possible, but is not used in current English. If you are a learner, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions would suit you better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it acceptable to use "is become" instead of "has become"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become) 'She is gone' (the be-perfect) would only ever be used nowadays in a dramatic / historic setting. It would never be contracted to 'she's gone' etc.

Answer (score -2):

This is a little confusing; you can tell from the context; "to be gone" means to be have disappeared" or to have gone away" but also "to be dead"; here, obviously it's the first choice (she has diappeared *or* she went away) ([to be gone vs to have gone](https://jakubmarian.com/is-gone-vs-has-gone-in-english/)).

"she has gone", "he has gone" is not much used finally ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+be+gone%2Che+is+gone%2Che+has+gone.%2Cshe+has+gone.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20gone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20gone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20has%20gone%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20has%20gone%20.%3B%2Cc0)).

In constructions such as "he's/she's gone to" the verb is "have", and that is the regular present perfect.

Comment: While "he is gone" and "he has gone" may not be used very much finally, neither is "il est parti." *He is gone* at the end of a sentence is ***perfectly good English*** and there's absolutely no reason to discourage it's use.

Comment: See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+est+parti%3Afre_2012%2Cil+est+parti.%3Afre_2012%2Che+is+gone%2Che+is+gone.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20est%20parti%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20est%20parti%20.%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20gone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20gone%20.%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20est%20parti%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20est%20parti%20.%3Afre_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20gone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20gone%20.%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @PeterShor That is just a typing mistake: read "he has gone", check the ngram I joined to that statement. Anyway, I do not discourage the use of it.